# Add additional noise to Captcha image?

Tags: php, captcha, gdlib

I have this simple captcha script from online. I like it, and I edited it to suit my site, but was wondering if someone could edit it to add some random lines on the captcha itself as it is somewhat too simple.

I did find tutorials on how to do it but it was not working for me.

Here is the simple captcha script; I would love to modify it to have some random lines appear on the captcha:

```
   $width    = 150;
   $height   = 24;
   $length   = 5;
   $font     = 'caviardreams.ttf';
   $font_size   = 14;
   $bg_color = array(245, 245, 245);
   $chars    = 'ABCDEFGHKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789';
   session_start();
   //putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
   $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
   $bkgr = imagecolorallocate($img, $bg_color[0], $bg_color[1], $bg_color[2]);
   imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $width, $height, $bkgr);

   $code = '';
   for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
   {
      $code .= $chr = $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
      $r = rand(0, 192);
      $g = rand(0, 192);
      $b = rand(0, 192);
      $color = imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);
      $rotation = rand(-35, 35);
      $x = 5+$i*(4/3*$font_size+2);
      $y = rand(4/3*$font_size, $height-(4/3*$font_size)/2);
      imagettftext($img, $font_size, $rotation, $x, $y, $color, $font, $chr);
   }

   $_SESSION['random_txt'] = md5($code);

   header("Content-type: image/png");
   header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jul 1998 05:00:00 GMT");
   header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
   header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
   header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
   header("Pragma: no-cache");

   imagepng($img);
   imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: Why not just use a great captcha script already made and free to use?  It is called `recpatcha` and is available from http://www.recaptcha.org

Comment: That would be: http://www.recaptcha.org/

Comment: Hi i always did use recaptcha but i dislike it now, i don't like the fact that if javascript is disabled by user it displays awful on the webpage plus it's to clunky hence why i ditched recaptcha after using it for about 2 years, i redesigned my website and it just does not suit my site, plus i got 2 other methods that i have implemented with the captcha to help prevent spambots. I am just looking for someone to alter the code to add random lines for me if they don't mind, i don't want to use any other scripts i want to keep to this one as it's simple and not bogged down. Thanks

Comment: Then use SecurImage PHP Captcha. It works fine on GD and required NO javascript: http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

Comment: Hi as i said i don't want to use anyother script thank you, i am not asking that, i don't want to sound rude but i asked if someone could kindly alter it for me not suggest captcha scripts, i know about them already, thank you.

Comment: SO is not for asking others to do your work for you.  Could you explain the difficulties you are having and ask questions about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right before:

```
$_SESSION['random_txt'] = md5($code);
```

Insert:

```
for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
  imageline($img,mt_rand(0,$width),mt_rand(0,$height),mt_rand(0,$width),mt_rand(0,$height),imagecolorallocate($img,rand(0,63),rand(0,63),rand(0,63)));
```

Comment: Thank stillstanding, much appreciate your time and help :) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to stick with that script, you can look at [this scripts](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-captcha.php) source and figure out how the do the design patterns. Sorry if this is not the answer you are looking for. The sections I would highlight for you to concentrate on would be:

```
/* generate random lines in background */
/* generate random dots in background */
```

Both of those items seem to be right up your alley of what you are wanting to do.